# Regular expression that matches two XML tags

Tags: xml, regex

I just started learning regular expressions.

How can I write a regular expression which will match two XML tags (with no attributes) which are not nested correctly (e.g. `<a-tag>> another-tag> /a-tag another-tag`)
You should use grouping and back references.

My effort: `<(bo)\\s+?(.+?)>(.*?)</bo>`

Comment: What are some examples of matching strings?

Comment: @MattB e.g. <a-tag> <another-tag> </a-tag> </another-tag>
You should use grouping and back references.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse non-regular languages like XML or HTML. See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks for editing and everything.

Comment: That's a hopelessly ill-specified question. How do you define "XML tag" except by reference to the XML specification, which requires tags to be nested correctly? And what do you want your output to be - a boolean which tells you whether your input string matches, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>
```

Comment: Know the next question as well?

Comment: Nah I'm still working on it, has something to do with word boundaries though - http://www.dreambank.net/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the letter "j", use `\bj\b`.